# Complex wolframalpha ajax query

Tags: javascript, ajax, wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I want to write formulas in Mathematica format in my blog, inside tag's formula. What js should I use (and what libary), to replace those tag's, with http://www.wolframalpha.com/ search result image, when Dom gets loaded?

For example:

```
<formula>Limit[((3 + h)^(-1) + -1/3)/h, h -> 0]</formula>
```

gets replaced with:
[image]

If it's to complex or can not be done with javascript, please explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use wolframalpha [API service](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/webserviceapi.html), but it's not [free](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/pricing.html) and you can't do this using javascript because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), only using server-side language.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your real question is: "how do I get nice math on Blogger.com", so I will answer this instead.

A proven solution (see e.g. [Psychedelic Geometry](http://psychedelic-geometry.blogspot.com/2010/07/totient-carnival.html), no affiliation) is to use the [MathTex](http://www.forkosh.com/mathtex.html) system by John Forkosh (who also hosts a public cgi) together with the [ReplaceMath](http://mathcache.appspot.com/static/docs.html) script by Randall Farmer. Browse some source for modified versions of the script.

Installation is a matter of including a single javascript file, after which you can inline LaTeX in your html as `$latex <some LaTeX to be png'ified> $`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format output from Wolfram Alpha then @antyrat is correct.  But if you just want to write nice-looking mathematical expressions for your blog you should look at Presentation MathML and LaTeX.  There is a variety of utilities for rendering LaTeX into gif or png or similar formats.

Comment: As i'm using blogger, i don't see how that is an option. Besides I assume that Mathematica Cell->Convert To->Bitmap + (Piscasa auto Sync) + drag & drop, should also work.